# How to click on an anchor element using VBA in a webform

Tags: excel, vba

Can you give me here some code by which I can click on anchor label on a webpage. I want click on the "Configuration"label. These labels are used to navigate from one page to another page. Here is some part of the Web page view source.

```
<td class="tabtext-unsel"><nobr><a href="/aems/catalog/cataloglist.do" class="tabtext-unsel">Catalogs</a></nobr></td>


<td class="tabtext-sel"><nobr><a href="/aems/configuration/configurationlist.do" class="tabtext-sel">Configuration</a></nobr></td>
```

Comment: Please add more information about why you want to click this and what you want to archieve.

Comment: I want to click on the Configuration label, and after which it will help me to navigate to a new page.this is how the third party web page had been designed. I am trying to automate it.

Comment: Maybe you need something like web scraping? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Comment: Actually i want the code of how to do such activity in VBA.. need lines of sample code also...

Comment: But why excel? You want to get data or what?

Comment: See i am writing some automatic scripting using VBA,which will log into the Web page and then will navigate to the correct page and will start some activities that we used to do manually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion in comments i can suggest another answer:

[Automation and Scripting Language](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

You may use this to navigate complicated pages, automate work in any application etc. It can copy almost any data and paste it to excel for example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

[Youtube: MrExcel's Learn Excel #665 - Scraping Webpages](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9V5E_LPiKs)

There is a technique called [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).

You may find many tutorials about web scraping, there are some tutorials for excel.

Comment: I want my script to click such anchor labels in that webpage as per the logic and can navigate to the right page. But i don't know how to do that?

Comment: VBA does not provide "click" functionality. You may open URL-s, get data from specyfic tag in html document. You should read about Excel Web scraping or see that youtube video. You will see what is possible in VBA and what is not.

Comment: Does .VBS support such functionality which i am looking for?

Comment: In my opinion - no. For clicking things you need some other tool, like AutoIt or other automation software.